# Laravel model: complex query from external database?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

New to Laravel, be kind. :-)

I have an external read-only legacy database.
I use a complex query to retrieve the "**top products**" from a Products table. 
This is an expensive query, which should be cached (only update once a day if necessary). The parameters for the query: top products since date xyz, max # of results (default: 500).

The database is completely read-only. It is not possible to create a view (which was the [solution to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028962/making-a-laravel-model-use-complex-query-as-table)).

I would like to be able to treat these top products as a regular model in Laravel.
This so that I can apply relationships / filters. E.g. check Purchase model for purchases for a "top product", get "top products" that have vendor value "xyz".

What is the best approach?

Comment: Is this query in a stored procedure? Or are you planning to rewrite it using Eloquent?

Comment: it is a complex regular query (not a stored procedure), with sub-SELECTs for some of the FROMs and JOINs. I was planning to treat it as raw T-SQL.

Comment: I would look into rewriting in Eloquent as far as you possibly can. There are the `whereRaw()` and `selectRaw()` methods so even if you have to drop down to raw SQL on occasion you can still get the benefits of an ORM.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to run a query like this is usually to run it in a stored procedure. You can define the stored procedure in a migration to ensure it's defined in the database and run it with something like this:

```
DB::select('exec my_stored_procedure(?,?)', [$a, $b]);
```

However, it's my understanding that this won't play well with Eloquent (I haven't had the occasion to try this approach before). You can convert the response into a collection by wrapping it in `collect()`, and that might help, but that would mean doing the sorting and filtering in PHP, which will always be less performant than doing so in SQL.

Alternatively, you can rewrite the whole thing using Eloquent and make it a method on the model.

If you need to refine this query further in SQL, the way to do so would be to define a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes) on the model that constrains the query, as in this example:

```
public function scopeTopProducts($query)
{
    return $query->where('a', true);
}
```

Then you can call `MyModel::topProducts()->find(1)`, safe in the knowledge that the scope will have constrained the queryset.

It's possible to cache the responses using [Laravel's caching system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache#retrieving-items-from-the-cache). However, for the latter method you can't cache a scope, only the result of the final query. If that's likely to cause a problem you may be better off just populating the initial data with a single query that can be cached and using [Laravel's collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) to filter the data down further instead of SQL.

Comment: Thanks Matt. It seems I need to learn quite a bit more before I can proceed! I don't think migration is applicable. The legacy database is completely read-only, my app can not make any modifications. Caching the result of the final query is fine (in fact: wanted). I guess I will have to park this until my knowledge has improved.

Comment: @wivku Using Laravel's collections, you can get quite good filtering in place. If you eager-load any relations you need using the `with()` method in Eloquent, those relations will then be pulled in with the results. You can then use the methods in Laravel's collections (which are mixed into the Eloquent response too) to sort and filter the results. I'd be very surprised if you can't get what you need that way.

Comment: @wivku Put it this way, Laravel collections include map and reduce operations, and using those it's possible to carry out some extremely complex operations on data. If you want to cache the responses and then continue operating on the data that's probably your best bet.